# Monotouch Automated Incremental Build Number with version number

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, version, auto-increment

Regarding Monotouch IOS development with C#:

I'm trying to implement an auto incrementing build version number into my Monotouch IOS project.  Something like [Major].[Minor].[Build] would be fine with the [Build] part auto incrementing on every build.

I found this post below but it seems to be using Objective C and I can't figure out how to get this working using Monotouch C#.

http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/How-to-increment-the-iPhone-Application-Version-number-on-every-build-td4425363.html

In Monotouch, I have access to "System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute", but I don't know how to use it.  I tried simple things like:

```
System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute tempvar = new System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute ("1.2.*");

Console.WriteLine("tempvar = " + tempvar.Version);
```

But the print output is literally:  "1.2.*" and doesn't auto increment.

Anyone experienced with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute` is meant to be used as an attribute. The compiler will replace the `*` with a number. E.g.

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute ("1.2.*")]
```

You might also want to look at this [email](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Displaying-Bundle-Version-in-Settings-Solved-FYI-tt4656018.html) for how the use your application bundle version.

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out I just didn't know how to access the Attribute's value correctly.  Your reply and this link were very useful http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-obtain-value-assemblyversion-attribute-t1297938.html.  After setting the Attribute as you did above, I used the following line of code to access it:  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()

Comment: Thanks @poupou for solution and Lampshade for implementation!

Comment: Where would you set the assembly attribute? It's normally in the AssemblyInfo.cs, but I don't have that in my project.

Comment: @lordscarlet `AssemblyInfo.cs` is an IDE generated file (for some project types) that includes the attribute (by default). However the attribute can be used anywhere (in your project/assembly) source code.

Comment: disregard -- I had it as an attribute of the class, that was the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you tried to add it inside a `class` declaration. Since the scope is assembly then it should be outside any class / namespace.